# Is there a book that I could buy that has detailed technical instructions for jump-starting technology in post apocalypse, post industrial future

Tags: technology, post-apocalypse

So, I'm not rich so construction of an underground bunker and stockpiling it with food and medical supplies  is a pipe dream (love that this coloquialism refers to opi-smoke dreams). So I've been thinking: what is an affordable, portable and sustainable post apocalypse currency I can invest in now?

Information!

To that end I was hoping someone has done some research and figured out what technology a post industrial society would be most important to get running again? Mains power? Transport infrastructure? Farming? Medicine? Then where a budding Rick Grimes (Walking Dead reference there) should start. What facilities could be practically jury-rigged (mains power from renewables? Mains gas? Petrol stations?) What order this should be done in (or. Perhaps - use the mains gas before it leaks away/ pressure builds up... For example). Slightly longer term, what machines should be saved and most coveted? I thought maybe electric cars and solar panels, drinkable spring water and maybe even smartphones which could be used to create a kind of hive WiFi where everyone in a settlement can connect to everyone else. Does this software exist? A micro sd/ usb-c hard drive and smart phone might actually be more useful than a book as can be indexed and searched more easily, plus software.... Also is there an e-ink, low power, post apocalypse smart phone with a battery that lasts like an old Nokia?

Longer term still, what 5-10 crops will grow in bulk, without Haber Bosch fixed fertilizer, requires little effort to harvest without specialist machines? Can things like transistors and photovoltaic cells be made in a DIY process??

These are just some of the things I would hope to have in my manual!

Comment: I wonder if maybe this question was asked so thoroughly "in-character" that the community believed you are asking for real-world book recommendations. You may have better luck if you rephrase it to be an explicit statement of the fictional scenario.

Comment: To further enhance Tom's comment, you need to ask one question per post only. You can learn more about what kind of question is accepted and how to better formulate them in the [tour] and [help/on-topic] :).

Comment: This is obviously a worldbuilding question. Am voting to reopen on principle. Note to James Unna: please convert ALL the subquestions in your query body to 'statements of things to be considered' or else you're likely to run into another mod hammer for asking too many questions.

Comment: @elemtilas even if it were so, FIRST the user should edit the question, THEN we would vote to reopen. Not the contrary.

Comment: @L.Dutch -- My VTR is based on the closure reason given. We can burn the other bridges if we ever get to them!

Comment: See Neal Stephenson's "Anathem" and clock project , and every one of Larry Niven's books involving the Protectors.